# Calculating logarithms in PHP - reason for floating point weirdness

Tags: php, precision, logarithm

I stumbled upon this strange(?) behaviour in PHP (5.4.6) while calculating some logarithms. What I needed was a base 2 logarithm, and in short - this is what happened:

```
$l1 = log(8, 2);
var_dump("LOG", $l1);
var_dump("FLOOR", floor($l1));
```

and the output was:

```
string(3) "LOG"
float(3)
string(5) "FLOOR"
float(2)
```

Perhaps it's normal for `floor(float(3))` to be equal to `float(2)` due to floating point inprecission, but I can't find a reasonable explaination.

I solved the problem with

```
$l2 = log(8)/log(2);
var_dump("LOG", $l2);
var_dump("FLOOR", floor($l2));
```

which returned:

```
string(3) "LOG"
float(3)
string(5) "FLOOR"
float(3)
```

as expected.

I wouldn't be posting this, but it cost me an hour of debugging today, so maybe someone can explain what happened here and why?

Comment: Strange. Both `var_dump(log(8, 2))` and `$l = log(8, 2); var_dump($l);` gives me `float(3)`.

Comment: What's your version of PHP? What OS?

Comment: I'm using PHP v. 5.5.4, and I'm running it on my windows 8 computer with Abyss Web Server.

Comment: Huh. Take a look at http://3v4l.org/rcCvm -- according to that utility, versions 4.3.0 to 5.6.0 have the exact same output, which is float(3). This included 5.4.6 specifically.

Comment: so maybe it's not specific to PHP, but to my system, I'll take a look at the PHP source code, see how `log` is implemented ...

Comment: What version of Windows and what CPU do you have? That might shed some light.